# Find the values between percentiles in a frequency distribution

Tags: r, distributions, skewness, quantiles, frequency

In the distribution below, how would I find the values that lies between 30% and 50% of the distribution? R code would be handy but not essential!

28, 28, 29, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38

Comment: You need to specify better your question. Is it about probability or frequency? In the later case, a simple question of interpolation in the frequency empirical distribution.  If you want inference, like confidence intervals, we need more.

Comment: Question edited. Don't need inference/confidence intervala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you just want the **quantiles** of the sample! If you do not know what they are, look at wikipedia:  https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Quantile
When specified by percent values, quantiles are called percentiles.

Here is some simple R code:

```
 d <- c(28, 28, 29, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38)
 quantile(d,c(0.3, 0.5))
 30%  50% 
30.8 31.0
```

Comment: thanks, you've answered my question. But regarding terminology, I didn't want to quantiles, did I? The quantiles are 0.3 and 0.5, so I wanted the values at the point of these quantiles (whatever these values are called).

Comment: luciano [quantiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Quantile) are sample values (*order statistics*), or sometimes, weighted averages of adjacent order statistics. The median is the 0.5 quantile, $x_{0.5}$.

Answer (score 2):

Since you specifically asked for the elements of the vector meeting your condition:

> how would I find the values that lies between 30% and 50% of the distribution

```
test=c(28,28,29,30,30,31,31,31,31,32,32,32,34,35,36,37,38)
q.30=quantile(test,0.30)
q.50=quantile(test,0.50)
test[(test[]>=q.30)&((test[]<=q.50))]
```